# find all digits between a character in python

Tags: python, regex

This might be an easy question but I can not get the result that I want!

I have a text like the one below:

```
text = 'To get to the destination follow this direction
1. First turn left and then
text text text
2. Secondly you have to some text here
some text here

For the second instruction follow the text below:
«1. some text some text some text
text text text.
2. some text some text text text text.
3. some text some text text text text.»'
```

I am using regex in python and I want to get all the numbers between these characters "«" "»" that is 1. 2. and 3.

I tried something like this:

```
test = re.findall(r'[«.*?](\d+)[.*?»]', text, re.DOTALL)
```

or this:

```
patt = re.findall(r'«.*?(\d+).*?»', text, re.DOTALL)
```

and many others but none of them return what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Both patterns just return the number 1 without any other digit. What about number 2 and 3?

Comment: I think you have to use lookahead and lookbehind, otherwise the `<` and `>` are only mathed once, thus you get just one number.

Comment: If I use lookahead or lookbehind don't I have to specifically tell regex how many characters to look behind or ahead for << and >> @tobias_k ?

Comment: @bettas for lookbehind that is the case, yes, for lookahead - no. I'm working on a combination of lookaheads and capturing groups to find a solution for you. Getting multiple results with a single contraint is not easy to do with regex, it'd be easier to do with multiple matches in sequence.

Comment: For only checking to be before `»` [one with a lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/qH0dG6/1): `\d+(?=[^«]*»)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text = '''To get to the destination follow this direction
1. First turn left and then
text text text
2. Secondly you have to some text here
some text here

For the second instruction follow the text below:
«1. some text some text some text
text text text.
2. some text some text text text text.
3. some text some text text text text.»'''


print re.findall(ur"\d+",re.findall(ur"«([\s\S]*?)»",text)[0])
```

or

```
print re.findall(ur"\d+","\n".join(re.findall(ur"«([\s\S]*?)»",text)))
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: yes!That works @vks! But I am still concerned why to use regex for such problems! Anyway I will use this pattern! Thanks a lot!